# Memory leaks during readFileSync() in cycle for multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, jsdom

After about 600 parsed files I get memory leaks error.

My source: https://github.com/SageBear/mentorhack/blob/master/src/fl_parser/parse.js

If I use --max-old-space-size v8 node.js flag it works, but become slower and slower...

How to fix that?

Comment: Is it JSDOM memory leak or a `readFileSync` memory leak?

Comment: I think readFileSync

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Have you tried invoking `fs.close` to force closing the file descriptors?

Comment: @bastos.sergio after I changed read and append to: https://pastebin.com/e91gG3fj
I get the same result.

Comment: @Bergi it turns out jsdom leaks https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/154, thanks for the hint. Do you know what to use to profile functions for memory leaks (for the future)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in jsdom - it leaks: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/154. After I've replaced it by cheerio, I got what I wanted.

Comment: Hi, your original source is no longer available and if you dont mind to share your updated code solution as well